# Alternatives of goto and jump commands

Tags: language-agnostic, goto

I am working on a language where there is not any `goto`,`jump` function. For example, Matlab.
Can you please help me on how to avoid using it? Is there any simple trick solving my problem?

Comment: If there is no `goto` in MATLAB then you should have no trouble avoiding it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jump in m-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082605/jump-in-m-file)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using `break` and `continue`

Instead of:

```
for ...
   ...
   if ...
      goto nextstuff:
   end
end
nextstuff:
```

You can do:

```
for ...
   ...
   if ...
      break
   end
end
```

And as @andrey said, you can often replace `goto` by `if-else`

Instead of doing:

```
if cond
  goto label
end
...
foobar()
...
label:
foobar2()
```

you can do:

```
if ~cond
  ...
  foobar()
  ...
end
foobar2()
```

When you use a goto to go back, you can replace it by a while:

Instead of doing:

```
redothat:
foobar()
...
if cond
   goto redothat;
end
```

you can do:

```
while cond
  foobar()
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and I am sorry for the wrong tag.My problem is that i want to implement a state diagram (trellis coding) and i have to go back in my code.I dont know if there is something obvious where i cant see (quite possible) but i cant find the solution.

Comment: You should describe in more details your problem, if you want a less general answer...

Comment: I have a sequence of 100  random (binary) numbers.

Comment: If you don't wna t a general answer, you should describe why (in your particular case) you think you need to use `goto`. I suggest you to post another question.

Comment: I am sorry for the 'I have a sequence of 100 random (binary) numbers' i wanted to add more but i pressed enter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you might as well ask it *without* the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag, you might get better answers. That is because this kind of question is common to almost all of the modern languages.

Instead of `goto` and `jump` you should use either conditionals like `if`,`if-else` or loops like `while`,`for`, depending on what you want to achieve.

Check out [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful), [Why is goto poor practise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443655/why-is-goto-poor-practise).

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrey mention you can use `if` or `if-else` statement. In many cases loops like `while`, `for` is one-to-one replacements to the `if-else` and `goto`.

You should also consider to use `break` and `continue` statement as @Oli said above.

In some rare cases you can use exception (I don't know whether the Matlab supports it) in order to "go back". This is somewhat controversial, but maybe in your case it will fit.

```
redothat:
foobar()
...
```

And inside foobar() in some place you have

```
if cond
   goto redothat;
end
```

you can do:

```
while(true){
 try {
   foobar();
   ...
   break;
 }
 catch(YourApplicationException e){
   //do nothing, continiue looping
 }  
}
```

And inside foobar() in some place you have

```
if cond
  throw YourApplicationException();
end
```

Or you can do something like this:

you can do:

```
boolean isOk = false;   
while(! isOk){
 try {
   foobar();
   ...
   isOk=true;
 }
 catch(YourApplicationException e){
   //do nothing, continiue looping
 }  
}
```