# Why is there no goto statement in Python?

Tags: python, goto

There is no goto in python, but what is the reason behind the unavailability of goto in python 2.X?

Please tell me.

Comment: What would be the reason for including it?

Answer (score 13):

From the [Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-is-there-no-goto):

> ## Why is there no goto?
>
> You can use exceptions to provide a “structured goto” that even works across function calls. Many feel that exceptions can conveniently emulate all reasonable uses of the “go” or “goto” constructs of C, Fortran, and other languages.

In other words: there is no need for `goto` when you have exception handling.

Comment: Yes, between exceptions AND loops, there is no need, see a quick tutorial on looping: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/loops-tutorial.php

Answer (score 2):

You can do every thing using `if`, `else` , `while` and `for` constructs, adding `goto` means  unstructured programming. `goto` don't add any extra power in language, its just an unconditional loop.

[**Why is goto poor practise?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443655/why-is-goto-poor-practise) and

[**GOTO still considered harmful?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

Comment: If you are going to refer to that, also make explicit mention to the respective paper presented by Knuth on the subject at 1974.

Comment: @mmgp Ahaa!! I didn't read ...can you add for me in my answer..:)

Answer (score 2):

Even in languages like FORTRAN, where there is still a GOTO, it's not usually recommended that you use it:

http://books.google.com/books?id=D0HOaW-5svQC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=fortran+scientists+and+engineers+goto&source=bl&ots=NWYj9wa2y3&sig=TH0NEPkqNtNQgprVpBn912WHJAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WoftUKiJDcuv0AGM-4DYCQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=fortran%20scientists%20and%20engineers%20goto&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Python saw the error in their ways, and added a [goto](http://entrian.com/goto/download.html)!

**Just Kidding - please don't use in real code**

It was released as an April Fools Joke.